# Discord role scraping

Tags: discord

Is there a way to scrape my server to get user details and roles in a spreadsheet so I can do filtering/sorting by roles? I want to be able to exclude roles when I'm searching for specific members but discord only allows for inclusionary filtering.

I haven't tried anything because I'm not really sure how to approach the problem to start with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the official Discord API if you want to programmatically interface with the server/guild.

https://discord.com/developers/docs/intro

You'd need to create a bot in the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers), then invite the bot to your server/guild. From there, your bot has access to all the information already! You'll have to define a way to instruct your bot one way or another to export the information, and import it somewhere else if necessary.

The most convenient way would be through commands which you can either issue in chat, or through the terminal if you make your script read from STDIN.

There are wrappers for this API available for many programming languages, some popular options include:

- .NET - [Discord.Net](https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net)
- Java - [JDA](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA)
- JavaScript - [discord.js](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js)
- Python - [discord.py](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py)
- Rust - [serenity](https://github.com/serenity-rs/serenity)

The endpoint you want is [List Guild Members](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#list-guild-members), which will provide user and role information. Each wrapper will have an equivalent way to call this endpoint.

You may be able to hit the API endpoint yourself in an HTTP client like [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) to download and manually process the data yourself.